# Send data between activities while skipping one middle activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a simple login app with three activities.

`ActivityA` is the launcher activity and the login screen. `ActivityB` has two buttons, "Configure" and "Exit". And `ActivityC` is a screen for setting a new username and password.

I also have a class called User.

I need to send data from `ActivityA` to `ActivityC`. That data is an User object with the default values for password and username.

Here are the steps of what I need to do, in order:

1 - Launch the app with `ActivityA` and click a button ("Login") that sends me to `ActivityB`.

2 - Then, in `ActivityB` I need to click another button ("Configure") that should send me to `ActivityC`.

3 - From `ActivityC`, I set a new password and username and click a button ("Confirm") that should send me back to `ActivityA`.
In `ActivityA`, I need data from `ActivityC`. That data is an User object with the new values for password and username.

Here are the screens for Activities A, B and C, so it's easier to understand.

Here's `ActivityA`:

[image]

Here's `ActivityB`:

[image]

And here's `ActivityC`:

[image]

So far I've accomplished steps 1 and 2. But I don't know how I can send the data from `ActivityA` to `ActivityC` without launching `ActivityC` because when clicking the button in `ActivityA`, I'll call `ActivityB` instead. But the data still needs to be available to `ActivityC`.

I'm currently passing data from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB` and then to `ActivityC`. That works. But I'd like to know if that's unnecessary and if there's a better way. Because while i only currently have 3 activities, if I had more it would become complicated to keep on chaining the activities like that, right?
So far I only know how to pass data with Intent.

I'd also like to pass the full object, if possible. As opposed to just passing the fields of said object (String, int, etc).

If there's way, how can I achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Can you send data from activity A to activity B?

Comment: Like I said, I could send data from A to B to C. But I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid that. Because while I only have 3 activities right now, if I had more it would be a bit complicated chaining all of them together so I could pass data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shared preferences for that.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: But can I pass a custom object using shared preferences? It seems it has built-in mehods like putString or putInt, but what if the data I want to pass is a custom object?

Comment: Why do you need pass object? Just pass fields of object (name, pass and etc) as string for example.

Comment: Is there no way to pass the full object?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question,  the best way to do it to use `Intent` to send data from `activity c` and display it in `activity a`.

And here how to use Intent:

```
Intent SendData = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityA.class);
SendData.putExtra("user_name", NewUserEditText.getText().toString();
SendData.putExtra("password", PasswordEditText.getText().toString();

startActivity(SendData);
```

Then back to your log in  activity
*where you want to fetch/recieve these values and do it.*

```
//here your edit text where you will put value
EditText userEditText = findViewById(R.id.user_edit_text);
EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text);

//this string to fetch/receive user_name and password Values from activity C...
//You should write getStringExtra value the same as you wrote it in activity C...
String name = getIntent.getStringExtra("user_name");
String password = getIntent.getStringExtra("user_name");

///set values inside edit text...
userEditText.setText(name); 
passwordEditText.setText(password);
```

To enter values one time and receive it each time you open your application , you should use `SharedPreferences`

And here how to do it ..
*In activity C*

```
//create Shared Preferences...
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();

// get values from EditText ..
String name_string= NewUserEditText.getText().toString();
String password_string = PasswordEditText.getText().toString();

//Storing data as KEY/VALUE pair
editor.putString("user_name", name_string);     // Saving  name string

editor.putString("password", password_string );  // Saving password string

// to Save the changes in SharedPreferences
editor.apply(); // commit changes
```

Then back to activity a ..where you want to recieve stored values

```
String name =pref.getString("user_name", "enter user name");         // getting name String
String password=pref.getString("password", "");        // getting password String

/*
*If value for key not exist then return second param value
* if values here don't exist in (ex. user_name), it will return "enter user name"
*/

//use these values in EditText
UsernameEditText.setText(name);
PasswordEditText.setText(password);
```

You will enter values only one time , and when you open app again values will appear in activity a ...and when you change them , values will change ...

I hope this helps you

Comment: It doesn't have to be by using Intent. I was looking into using sharedpreferences. I just don't know how to do it yet. But I'll try your approach. Thank you!

Comment: But how would I pass data from ActivityA to ActivityC? That's my main problem actually.

Comment: You can pass data with same way.. Send Intent from activity a and recieve it in  activity c

Comment: But how would I do that without starting Activity C? I'm sorry but I'm a little confused. Could you demonstrate?

Comment: Yes in this case you should use `SharedPreferences` which will help you to store **string**,  **int** or **long** values.. and fetch them at any time you want

Comment: I will update my answer with (how to use sharedPeferences in your app )

Comment: But what if the data I want to pass is a custom object? Can I still do it with shared preferences?

Comment: Shared Preferences can store  small values like someone name , age , weight , height ,etc...can store String, int, float, Boolean or long; but can't store large objects like arraylist or HashMap values

Comment: Is there no way to pass a full, custom object? As opposed to just passing fields of that object, I mean.

Comment: I think no way to do it